# Android SDK Version 26 + java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity : java.lang.IllegalStateException: LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-appcompat, onresume, activity-lifecycle

```
W: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity: java.lang.IllegalStateException: LinearLayout
W:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4158)
W:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4252)
W:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3363)
W:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:223)
W:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1797)
W:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
W:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7231)
W:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
W:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
W: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: LinearLayout
W:     at android.support.v7.app.WindowDecorActionBar.getDecorToolbar(WindowDecorActionBar.java:242)
W:     at android.support.v7.app.WindowDecorActionBar.init(WindowDecorActionBar.java:198)
W:     at android.support.v7.app.WindowDecorActionBar.<init>(WindowDecorActionBar.java:172)
W:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.initWindowDecorActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:182)
W:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.getSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:145)
W:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onPostResume(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:267)
W:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onPostResume(AppCompatActivity.java:172)
W:     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7017)
W:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4147)
```

Getting this error on android version 26 only. 
My Activity extends AppCompactActivity If extends normal Activity it does not crashes.
com.android.support:appcompat-v7

Comment: Can you put your source code as well?

Comment: Fixed exception by this method " this.onPostResume(); " before initializing screen ui, call in own activity which extends AppCompactActivity.